# Page Redirection

Tags: javascript, redirect

To help better explain my Question, here is what i have:

I am using a Precoded service, on it i have access to the Template HTML Files Only.

The URL to the Login page is : DynamicPage.aspx?Site=Mysite&WebCode=LoginRequired

The Main site URL would look like : DynamicPage.aspx?Site=Mysite&WebCode= or DynamicPage.aspx?Site=Mysite

What i need is a JavaScript I could put into the main header template file that would view "WebCode" And depending on whats entered redirect to a certain page.

I got from "Sitifensys" a code

> Sitifensys
>
> `if (window.location.href!="foo.bar/login.php") window.location.href="login.php";`

The problem with this code is even when i go to the main page it still redirects me to login.php which i do not want it to. I need this code to Read the "WebCode" If it is "LoginRequired" Redirect to "Login.php" else if redirect to "Test.php"

Hope this explanation is a bit better.

Comment: Are you trying to do it in PHP or Javascript? The function you've provided looks like PHP (with the dollar signs)

Comment: can you post more code is you are dealing with session ?

Comment: This is in Javascript, read new post above.

Comment: So if the url string contains `WebCode=LoginRequired` you'll redirect right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as answered earlier, you should add a window.location.href="somepage" somewhere.

Some where in your script :

```
if (window.location.href!="foo.bar/login.php") window.location.href="login.php";
```

This doesn't need to be in a listener for the page load event.

EDIT :
Regarding your new descriptionn I would use (but would not recommend;)) something like :

```
if (location.pathname.indexOf("WebCode=LoginRequired")>0) {
    window.location.href="login.php";
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Yes problem is this redirects everypage to that url; even if i dont go to the page.
Will Modify top Post.

Comment: Read New Post itll say what i need better :)

Comment: Yes if it equils that url it will redirect to login if WebCode is somehting else it

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
window.location.href = "http://www.something.com/"
```

Comment: Yes but, i need to know how to grab if page is like index.php?pageid=login  then dont redirect if it is not pageid= then redirect

Comment: you have to grab it using $_GET[''] and check whether pageid=login then don't redirect otherwise redirect.

Comment: you can chk using the same variable:
var Wlocation = window.location.href
if( <your condition using Wlocation as a string > )
{
}
else
{
}

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this that way. If you do anything in JavaScript it may be easily blocked by user. Better add and if() in your PHP code and then redirect to login, if user don't have specific session key:

```
if(!(isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && true == $_SESSION['logged_in']))
    {
    header('Location: login.php');
    die();
    }
```

Comment: This is php Sorry didnt see PHP in the tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (location.pathname.indexOf(login.php) >= 0) {
   //don't redirect
} else {
   /...
}
```

Comment: this isn't coded in php then you are using new javascript with $variable

Answer (score 0):

You can add this script at the beginning of the `body` tag:

```
<body>
  <script>
    if((/WebCode\=LoginRequired/).test(window.location.href)){
      window.location.href = window.location.href.
        replace(/(\?|\&)WebCode\=LoginRequired/, '');
    }
  </script>
  ...
</body>
```